# How do youcompare average time elapsed versus static minute value?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

My data returns an average run time that needs to be greater than 9 minutes.  If it is less than 9 min then the row needs to be highlighted red.  Here is one of the various iif statements I have attempted to writer to cover this in the background color expression.  In the picture the top two rows should be highlighted in red.

`=iif(Fields!AvgTime.Value < TimeValue("00:09:00"),"#ffb3be","#c8ffcd")`

[image: Data rows Image]

Comment: Isn't "TimeValue" essentially a date's time-of-day? Wonder if it's not comparing apples to apples here. I could be wrong, haven't used that platform in a long time. What if you cast the average time to char and then < "00:09:00"

Comment: Is the AvgTime field a date/time or a text field?